# omniauth OAuthException & OAuth::Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

I have installed omniauth 1.0. Also I have oauth-0.4.5, oauth2-0.5.1, omniauth-facebook-1.0.0, omniauth-twitter-0.0.6.

```
omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :developer unless Rails.env.production?
  provider :facebook, ENV['167257285348131'],     ENV['c8c722f697scb2afcf1600286c6212a9'],     :scope => 'email,offline_access,read_stream', :display => 'popup'
  provider :twitter, ENV['fma2L22ObJCW52QrL7uew'], ENV['4aZfhCAOdiS7ap8pHJ7I1OZslFwVWWLiAMVpYUI']

end

session_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
require 'omniauth-facebook'
require 'omniauth-twitter'
require 'omniauth'

def create
    @user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    self.current_user = @user
    redirect_to '/'
end



def auth_hash
request.env['omniauth.auth']
end

end
```

Also I add 
     'omniauth'
     'omniauth-facebook'
    'omniauth-twitter' gems to gemfile

There are two problems:

1. When I go http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook  I get
   {
   "error": {
     "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
     "type": "OAuthException"
   }
   }

And the link graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&parse=query&scope=email%2Coffline_access%2Cread_stream&display=popup 
**And there is no client_id!!!**

2. When I go to http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter I get OAuth::Unauthorized

401 Unauthorized

Any ideas?

Comment: have you solved the facebook error? If it is, can I get the work around? I get same error message. It can be solved if I added manually the client_id to query string parameters

Comment: @Vina ENV[] breaks it. Try to use "" only. For ex.: provider :facebook, '167257285348131', 'c8c722f697scb2afcf1600286c6212a9'

Comment: Thanks, it work! It seems I also need to restart the webrick. :D

Comment: I was having this exact same problem! Do you know why ENV[] breaks this? In my case it works fine with facebook but not with twitter.

Comment: try to `source ~/.profile` (or wherever you have defined the env variables) before starting the server. you need to do this only once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alex D. is correct in that the ENV[] breaks it.  To create omniauth.rb so that it uses different keys in different environments just put:

```
provider :twitter, TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET
```

in omniauth.rb

and then in your environment config files (config/environments/development.rb, etc.) put the key you want to use for that environment.

config/environments/development.rb:

```
TWITTER_KEY = 'aaaaaaa'
TWITTER_SECRET = 'aaaabbbbbb'
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
TWITTER_KEY = 'ccccccc'
TWITTER_SECRET = 'ccccdddddd'
```

Comment: I take it you add these files to your gitignore file as otherwise there are lots of keys available for anyone to view in your repo?

Comment: @Jeff Steil: Is this a better way of storing KEY and API_SECRET or the environment variables approach? I know it's a debatable topic, but since I am currently the sole developer, which one is the better way?

Answer (score 2):

`ENV['something']`

looks into your environment vars for "something", so it would expect

`something='12345'`

so you should do it like that

```
export AUTH_FB_KEY='....'
export AUTH_FB_SECRET='...'
```

check with

```
env
```

and update your config

```
provider :facebook, ENV['AUTH_FB_KEY'], ENV['AUTH_FB_SECRET']
```

if you use heroku

```
heroku config:add AUTH_FB_KEY='....'
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been breaking changes made in omniauth 1.0 - https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

> OmniAuth 1.0 has several breaking changes from version 0.x. You can
>   set the dependency to ~> 0.3.2 if you do not wish to make the more
>   difficult upgrade. See the [wiki](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Upgrading-to-1.0) for more information.

I would try reverting omniauth to 0.3.2:

```
gem install omniauth --version '~> 0.3.2'
```

or if you're using bundler, in your Gemfile:

```
gem omniauth, '~> 0.3.2'
```

Comment: I reverted to 0.3.2. Surprising I have the same problems.

Comment: Ah sorry to hear that.  I had a similar issue a while back, and reverting to 0.3.2 solved it for me.  I'd check out the history logs on the other relevant gems, & just make sure everything looks sweet?

Comment: Thank you, but I found the reason in omniauth.rb. Without ENV[] it works.