# Twitter Omniauth error with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth

Hello I being trying to solve this issue, I am trying to integrate twitter omniauth without using the devise gem and is giving me the following error.

```
401 Unauthorized
```

My link in the sing in twitter is the following

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
```

my confing/initializers/omniauth.rb is settled down as follow

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

provider :twitter, ENV['xxxxx'], ENV['xxxxxxxxxxxx']

end
```

And for additional details I have already the app on the twitter setting turn on to allow sign in and have a callback url.

Thanks in for your help in advance.

Comment: when does the error happens ?

Comment: @oldergod it happens when you hit the link to sign in to twitter.

Comment: Is your callback url set to localhost ?

Comment: Yes @oldergod is running in localhost:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information on [OAuth::Unauthorized 401 int twitter-omniauth gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402975/oauthunauthorized-401-int-twitter-omniauth-gem)

If you said your callback url is set to localhost, I think it is the problem.

You could use a url shortner like http://goo.gl/ and replace your callback url with the one that fits you.

```
http://localhost:5000/ => http://goo.gl/6cpbd
https://localhost:5000/ => http://goo.gl/z6C77
```